# Openshift node_modules grows out of quota

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

I have an application in `node` on OpenShift, after adding some devDependecies into it, particularly `babel`, and pushin to the repo it stopped to build. The `node_modules` folder growing constantly until it reached the limit of quota.
It builds perfectly locally and npm dependencies kept quite small (about 7000 files) while on open shift number of files reached up to 80 000 files (which is the limit)!

After investigation of OpenSHift's repo i found following. 
Here is a part of `node_modules` on Open Shift (output of `du -sh` command)

```
308K    morgan
6.4M    request
108K    serve-favicon
```

And here is the output of the same command locally :

```
 16K    repeating
236K    request
 16K    right-align
```

the `request` module is `6M` vs `236K` if I investigate it on Open shift i see another `node_modules` folder which I do not have locally. So basically all modules get growing and growing and growing

Did any one ran into the same issue? Any ideas?

Here is my `package.json` file :

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "babel --presets es2015 -d lib/ src/",
    "start": "babel-node ./server.js --presets es2015",
    "test": "npm run compile && mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register src/test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "deferred": "^0.7.6",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mongodb": "^1.4.4",
    "monk": "^1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
    "tldjs": "^1.7.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^1.4.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "sinon": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem by rolling back to old plain `ES5` version and avoiding `babel` which seemed to download to much dependencies.